# What is an example of a function whose bounds on its error terms of its Taylor polynomials do not converge to 0, but the error itself converges to 0?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

My calculus textbook states that it is possible for bounds on the error terms of a Taylor series to converge to something other than 0, but the actual error converges to 0, and the series converges.

I couldn't think of any functions with this property, and couldn't find any on the internet. Can somebody provide an example?

Comment: If the error converges to $0$, it can eventually be bounded by a constant, say, $1$. Thus, the error bound, namely $1$, does not converge to $0$ but the error term itself does. You have to specify what you mean by an error bound.

Comment: I mean that the Lagrange error bounding of the terms do not go to 0, but the actual error converges to 0.

Comment: If by Lagrange error bound you mean that you take the maximum/supremum of the absolute value of the $n$th derivative in the Lagrange error term, try $\log(1+x)$ for $-1<x<-1/2$.

Comment: Is it possible that the Lagrange error terms are finite over an interval, and does not tend to zero, but the actual error tends to zero?

Comment: The Lagrange error term *is* the error, so it is impossible.

Comment: @Gary: That seems like a complete answer to me. (The question was to provide an example.)

Comment: There are examples for which the form of the remainder can be inconvienient for estimating, although it tends to zero. For example $f(x)=(1+x)^{-1/2}$  at$x=0$ the Lagrange formula for the remainder is inconvienient, while the Cauchy form is effective.